# How to choose which and when handlers will be executed?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, py-telegram-bot-api, aiogram

Let's say I have this code in Aiogram. I need that when the @dp.message(Text('Begin ')) handler is run, only the handlers that are inside this handler are checked. And when the user wrote End , then the handlers in @dp.message(Text('Begin ')) were no longer checked. And all that are outside this handler were checked

Minimal-reproducible-example:

```
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.filters import Text
from aiogram.filters.command import Command
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import ReplyKeyboardBuilder

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(token="TOKEN")
dp = Dispatcher()




@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    builder = ReplyKeyboardBuilder()
    builder.row(
        types.KeyboardButton(text="Begin"),
    )
    await message.answer('Hello, press to button',        reply_markup=builder.as_markup(resize_keyboard=True))


@dp.message(Text('Begin'))
async def new_client_services(message: types.Message):
    builder = ReplyKeyboardBuilder()
    builder.row(
        types.KeyboardButton(text="End"),
    )
    await message.answer("Please write down all your items lying on the table one by one",
                         reply_markup=builder.as_markup(resize_keyboard=True))

    @dp.message(Text('End'))
    async def end_save_services(message: types.Message):
        await message.reply("Excellent",
                            reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())

    @dp.message()
    async def with_puree(message: types.Message):
        #  add part mysql
        await message.answer(f"Items {message.text} add✅\n")


@dp.message()
async def end_save_services(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Please, push button")


async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I found[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69877071/how-to-execute-definite-handler-function-in-aiogram-telegram-api). This question has a similar problem but different

Comment: Sorry for closing the question - the wording of your problem, and your example program, differ from the ones there - but I think both approaches I suggest in the target question could work in your case. Nonetheless you have to switch to use TaskGroups, and change some of your code. Please, explain better what you want if that is not fit.